# Not sure how to fix "argument lists differ in length"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I need to create an application that calculates tax liability by accepting a user's annual income and marital status (stored here as "String marital" and "double income" respectively. I then need to pass these variables from my main class, "ShowTax" to a separate class "Tax" that calculates tax liability and returns that value to the main class to be output to the user. I'm 95% positive that I have everything set up correctly, but I keep getting this error:

> constructor Tax in class Tax cannot be applied to given types:
>
> required: no arguments
>
> found: String,double
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong....

Here is the relevant code from my ShowTax class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShowTax {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    

    System.out.print("Please enter Annual Income: $");
    double income = sc.nextDouble();
    
    while (income < 0) {
        System.out.print("ERROR: Income cannot be negative: ");
        income = sc.nextDouble();
   
    }
    
    System.out.print("Please Enter Marital Status (S/M): ");
    String marital = sc.next();
    
    while (!("S".equals(marital) || "s".equals(marital) || "M".equals(marital) || "m".equals(marital))) {
        System.out.print("ERROR: Try Again: ");
        marital = sc.next();
        if ("S".equals(marital) || "s".equals(marital) || "M".equals(marital) || "m".equals(marital)){
            break;
                    
        }
    }
    
    Tax myTax = new Tax(marital, income);
    

    }
}
```

And here is the code from my Tax class:

```
public class Tax{

    public double Tax(String marital, double income)
    {
        double taxRate;
        double liability=0;
        if (("s".equals(marital)||"S".equals(marital))){
            if (income >= 49002){
                taxRate=75;
                liability = (income - (income*(taxRate/100)));
            }
            else if (income > 15000){
                taxRate=50;
                liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
            }
            else {
                taxRate=25;
                liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
            }
        }
        else if ("m".equals(marital)||"M".equals(marital)){
            if (income >= 49002){
                taxRate=74;
                liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
            }
            else if (income > 15000){
                taxRate=49;
                liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
            }
            else {
                taxRate=24;
                liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
            }
        }
        return liability;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `public double Tax(...)` is not a constructor. It's a method named `Tax` that returns a `double`.

Comment: `public double Tax(...)` is not a constructor.

Comment: Constructors don't have a return type

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you would define a parameterised constructor for your `Tax` class like this:

```
public Tax(String marital, double income) {
    // …
}
```

This allows you to create a new *instance* of your `Tax` class.  However, it looks like you are trying to compute a tax liability (a `double` value), not create a new object instance?

In this case, you probably wanted a static method, something like:

```
public class Tax {
    public static double liability(String marital, double income) {
        // …
    }
}
```

You could call this by saying `double myTax = Tax.liability(marital, income);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an object of the class Tax doing

```
Tax myTax = new Tax(marital, income);
```

This expects the class Tax to have a constructor

```
public Tax(String marital, double income){...}
```

Which it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your `main()` method, you had the following line of code:

```
Tax myTax = new Tax(marital, income);
```

This will work if you have a constructor for your `Tax` class that will have two arguments. You did have a method in your `Tax` class that took two arguments but this was not your constructor.

```
public double Tax(String marital, double income)
```

It was a little confusing since both the method and the class had the same name. You can try using the following code to see if it helps:

```
public class Tax{

private String marital;
private double income;

Tax(String marital, double income)
{
    this.marital = marital;
    this.income = income;
}

public double CaculateTax()
{
    double taxRate;
    double liability=0;
    if (("s".equals(marital)||"S".equals(marital))){
        if (income >= 49002){
            taxRate=75;
            liability = (income - (income*(taxRate/100)));
        }
        else if (income > 15000){
            taxRate=50;
            liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
        }
        else {
            taxRate=25;
            liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
        }
    }
    else if ("m".equals(marital)||"M".equals(marital)){
        if (income >= 49002){
            taxRate=74;
            liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
        }
        else if (income > 15000){
            taxRate=49;
            liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
        }
        else {
            taxRate=24;
            liability = income - (income*(taxRate/100));
        }
    }
    return liability;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers have pointed out, you created a method called Tax, not a constructor.

The actual reason why the error `actual and formal argument lists differ in length` occurred, is because when you don't provide a constructor for a class, Java creates one for you with no arguments. This **default constructor** doesn't match the signature of the constructor you were trying to call.